# How to read a text file and assign the value of a specific line to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, txt

After sending data from another program into a txt file, I have each separate piece of data as a string on separate lines in the txt file. Now I'm attempting to separate them into variables, or use whatever method will permit me to display the lines at different spots. This is as far as I've gotten, but I don't understand why this isn't working. I was thinking another method would be to turn the lines into elements of an array, and index that way. The txt file is client-side, just in the same folder as the javascript file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="readfileautomatically();">

<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="line3"></div>

<script>
    function readfileautomatically () {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', 'Transfert2.txt');
        client.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( client.responseText != '' )
            {
                var txt = client.responseText.split("\n");
                document.getElementById("line1").innerHTML = txt[0];
                document.getElementById("line3").innerHTML = txt[2];
            }
        }
        client.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no obvious reason that wouldn't work. Do some debugging. Check the console for errors and the network tab to make sure the request contains what you expect.

Comment: "The txt file is client-side, just in the same folder as the javascript file." — That doesn't make sense. The client is the browser, but the HTML, JS, etc live on the server and are requested. Also, you don't have a JavaScript file, your JS is inline in the HTML.